# SQL Delete from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have two tables: 'player' and 'game'. 
The primary key of player is the foreign key in the table game.

```
'player' --> PK = idPlayer
'game'   --> FK = player_idPlayer
```

So now I want to delete one player in the players table. The SQL statement should also delete all entries of the game table where `idPlayer = player_idPlayer` - if there are some.

My statement only deletes when the player is in both tables. But i want to delete the player also when this player is not in the game table.

```
DELETE player, game 
FROM players, game 
WHERE idPlayer = player_idPlayer AND player_idPlayer = ?
```

Comment: You need two SQL queries to delete from two tables.

Comment: Or better yet, use cascade delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with a left outer join

```
DELETE p, g 
FROM players p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN game g ON g.player_idPlayer = p.idPlayer
WHERE p.idPlayer = ?
```